# site crashing ie7 completely?

Tags: browser, crash, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

hey guys,
i can't figure out why my latest web project is completely crashing ie7.
Either the browser is stuck or the browser even says "The program cannot display the page".

This is the link to the site: ...

any idea what could cause that? it works fine in ie8, ie9 and of course all other browsers like firefox, chrome, safari. I have nothing fancy going on on the site. just a normal wordpress site where I developed the theme. I'd just love to support ie7.

any idea?

Comment: Can you get fiddler to catch it without crashing IE?

Comment: I don't have IE on Ubuntu, but I wonder if the crash is an exploitable security vulnerability?

Comment: Best way would be to open the crash dump or browser in WinDbg. If crash address exceeds 0x1000, there is a good chance it is.

Comment: By "crash address" I mean the memory location the code is trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.clientcide.com/code-snippets/manipulating-the-dom/ie-and-operation-aborted/

I had plenty of problems with this 'feature' previously

Answer (score 0):

Really tough to say with your obfuscated code but I suspect you have a `setTimeout` in there that is set to 0 that may be removing elements. I know that can cause IE7 to hang/crash.